# Can I output the snort logs to a database?

Tags: mysql, snort

I'm using snort in win7. 
We know that using snort in its sniffer mode we can log a lot packets 
into a file, and now I want to log them to a mysql server. I enabled 
the database output plugin in the snort.conf and customed a rule:

```
log ip any any <> any any (sid:2000000;)
```

as a test.

Everything is OK and I used a PC whose ip is 172.18.186.186 to ping another 172.18.186.189. What I hope to get is 8 records, among which there would be 4 records and their `ip_src`es are 172.18.186.186. However I just got 4 records and their `ip_dst`s are 172.18.186.186 while the `ip_src`es are 172.18.186.189.

OK,that's my problem. How can I get the 8 records I want to see? Is it possible? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can check out [snorby](http://snorby.org/). and lot of implementation there are for connecting snort to a database, such as mysql or mongodb etc.

This [article](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/opensource/configure-snort-to-log-packets-to-mysql/184) explaing you how u can log to mysql.

Comment: actually,I can sucessfully log to mysql, but what confused me is that the outputplugin didn't log the packets of which the `ip_src`es were 172.18.186.186 as I mentioned in the question. Maybe they believed that the packets wouldn't interest me?

Comment: I wonder can I log into mysql in sniffer mode rather than IDS mode.

Comment: u said u were able to log it to mysql.

Comment: I'm sorry, but a few days ago I successfully logged what interests me after I deleted many configurations in snort.conf. I don't know what happened but it works! Thank you all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the output plugin unified2, because [direct SQL output is deprecated](http://manual.snort.org/node21.html) in the snort tree 2.9.2 and will be removed at some point.

[Barnyard2](http://www.securixlive.com/barnyard2/) is a binary capable of reading unified2 output and writing that data to a SQL, syslog, or other datasource.

FYI: Snorby is just a Ruby On Rails web app for a database schema for the ACID/BASE standard.